# How to determine the hostname in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to create some links in Oracle APEX to the application itself. But it changes in my development envireonment and the production environment. I need a way to determine my current hostname and port. Which function can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The necessary method is in the `APEX_UTIL`-package and called [`HOST_URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39149/apex_util.htm#AEAPI2311). With the parameter, you can extend the output:

Given your hostname is `example.com` and your port is `5883`.

```
function call                    |  result
---------------------------------|-----------------------------------
APEX_UTIL.HOST_URL()             |  http://example.com:5883
APEX_UTIL.HOST_URL('SCRIPT')     |  http://example.com:5883/pls/apex/
APEX_UTIL.HOST_URL('IMGPRE')     |  http://example.com:5883/i/
```

The result with the value `IMGPRE` depends on your configuration at Application Properties > User Interface > General Properties > Image prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to avoid generating absolute URLs like http://domain/apex/f?p=123 to the same application or other applications on the same system. Use relative URLs instead to avoid changing domain names. For example just use

f?p=&APP_ID.:5:&SESSION.

if you want to reference a specific page within your application. But where possible you should use declarative links which automatically generate what's necessary. If you want to reference another app use

```
f?p=123
```

Comment: Sometimes you need absolute links to the application, e.g. for e-mails and sending. In these cases, you need the hostname and etc.